# Embedding Powershell Script in Python Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, subprocess

I have a fully functional Powershell Script that produces an HTML report without any issues. I am trying to create a Python script to run the PowerShell script so that I can send the report out via email with Python and other reasons for where I work. This is the first time I am trying to run a Powershell script inside a Python script and I am still a novice at Python and am better with Python than Powershell. Researched this issue for 2-3 hours and am left scratching my head. My end goal is to create AD reports with Python but I have to learn that from scratch and the Powershell script I have does everything I need it to do for now.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe', 'C:\\Users\\wills.b\\Documents\\scripts\\ADHTMLREPORT.ps1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
print(result)
```

Error:

```
bryanwi09@KY-IT-002:/mnt/c/Users/wills.b/Documents/scripts$ python3 report.py
  File "report.py", line 2
    result = subprocess.run(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe', 'C:\Users\wills.b\Documents\scripts\ADHTMLREPORT.ps1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
bryanwi09@KY-IT-002:/mnt/c/Users/wills.b/Documents/scripts$ python3 report.py
CompletedProcess(args=['C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe', 'C:\\Users\\wills.b\\Documents\\scripts\\ADHTMLREPORT.ps1'], returncode=127, stdout=b'C:\\Users\\wills.b\\Documents\\scripts\\ADHTMLREPORT.ps1: 1: C:WindowsSystem32WindowsPowerShellv1.0powershell.exe: not found\n')
```

Comment: If you run the `.ps1` file from a Powershell prompt, does it work? If it does, then the problem is in Python part. If it doesn't, then it's in the Powershell part.

Comment: @vonPryz, yes the .ps1 script outputs an .html file which is then emailed.

Comment: `python3 report.py` differs from `python.exe report.py` in their results (WSL on Windows 10)…

Answer (score 0):

Change `'C:\Users\wills.b\Documents\scripts\ADHTMLREPORT.ps1'` from your original code snippet to    `r'C:\Users\wills.b\Documents\scripts\ADHTMLREPORT.ps1'` or to `'C:\\Users\\wills.b\\Documents\\scripts\\ADHTMLREPORT.ps1'` (see @Axe319's numb proactive edit).

```
import subprocess 
result = subprocess.run(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe',
    r'C:\Users\wills.b\Documents\scripts\ADHTMLREPORT.ps1'],      ### improved ###
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
print(result)
```

Read [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for explanation:

> Escape sequences only recognized in string literals are:
>
> ```
> Escape Sequence  Meaning                                      Notes
>
> \N{name}         Character named name in the Unicode database (4)
> \uxxxx           Character with 16-bit hex value xxxx         (5)
> \Uxxxxxxxx       Character with 32-bit hex value xxxxxxxx     (6)
> ```
>
> Notes:
> …
>
> 4. Changed in version 3.3: Support for name aliases 1 has been added.
> 5. Exactly four hex digits are required.
> 6. Any Unicode character can be encoded this way. **Exactly eight hex digits are required**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @JosefZ I will check this out later and let you know. Nearly forgot about this until you replied.